# Firefox scrollbar under the div with z-index set to 120

Tags: reactjs, firefox, react-typescript, handsontable

I am using **Handsontable** library with `fixedColumnsLeft` settings.
What it does is it creates a master table and for `fixedColumnsLeft` it clone those columns and create a new table over the master table and set `z-index` of cloned table to 120. so when user scroll table, Master table has overflow to auto and it scrolls under the cloned table with z-index of 120 giving the illusion of fixed columns just like MS Excel.

This works fine in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox scrollbar hides under the cloned table because it has higher z-index.

[image: sandboxImage]

This is the demo I have prepared. open this link in Firefox and scroll to right with touchpad gesture. You will see scrollbar emerging from under the fixed columns portion.

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kare-gpuubq?file=/src/App.tsx

How can I make the scrollbar z-index higher so that it show over the fixed column table?

I am using Firefox 113.0.1, checked it on Ubuntu and Windows.

I have reported the issue on GitHub as well. I need a workaround.

https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/10370